# ADFS 2.1 Trace Settings Windows Server 2012

Tags: adfs2.0, windows-server-2012, adfs2.1

When I tried to increase the ADFS Trace -log level using the [Microsoft instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1407.how-to-enable-debug-logging-for-active-directory-federation-services-2-0-ad-fs-2-0.aspx) , I am getting the below error:

> C:\Windows\system32>wevtutil sl "AD FS 2.0 Tracing/Debug" /L:5
>   Failed to read
>   configuration for log AD FS Tracing. The specified channel could not
>   be found. Check channel configuration.

Comment: Note that this command only works in PowerShell. If you execute it in a normal Command Prompt you will get, "Too many arguments are specified. The parameter is incorrect."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the solution(using [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wevtutil-error-specified-channel-not-found-event-log-file/) blog post)- The Log file names were changed in **ADFS 2.1 from AD FS 2.0 Tracing/Debug** to **AD FS Tracing/Debug**

Old Path:

> %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\AD FS 2.0 Tracing%4Debug.etl

New Path:

> %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\AD FS Tracing%4Debug.etl